# Cos'è uno "scontro di piazza"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Le otto montagne*, di Paolo Cognetti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Quaggiú da noi c’erano le fabbriche in tumulto, le case popolari sovraffollate, gli **scontri di piazza**, i bambini maltrattati, le ragazze madri; lassú la neve.

So cos'è uno "scontro" e so anche che "piazza" si usa in modo figurato per indicare manifestazioni collettive sulla strada, ma non so cosa sia uno "scontro di piazza". Ho cercato alla voce "scontro" di alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa espressione. L'ho riscontrata, però, nella definizione del vocabolo ["sedare" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI18/00432.jpg), quindi immagino abbia a che vedere con gli altri termini che appaiono lì, cioè, "tumulto", "insurrezione", "sollevazione popolare", "tafferuglio",  "rissa", ma che ci sia qualche sfumatura particolare che non conosco. Quindi, mi potreste spiegare il significato di "scontro di piazza"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La tua deduzione è corretta, uno "scontro di piazza" è una contrapposizione violenta (rissa o tumulto) tra due o più fazioni, che avviene in un luogo pubblico; si usa di solito per indicare lo scontro tra forze dell'ordine e manifestanti o scioperanti oppure tra due fazioni politiche contrapposte.